# roll back all inserts if an exception occured

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

i am trying to persist multiple entities to database. but i need to roll back all inserts if one of them faces an exception. how can i do that?
here is what i did:

```
public class RoleCreationApplyService extends AbstractEntityProxy implements EntityProxy {


    @Inject
    @Override
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        super.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Resource
   UserTransaction utx;
 public Object acceptAppliedRole(String applyId, Role parentRole, SecurityContext securityContext) throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        try {
            FilterWrapper filter = FilterWrapper.createWrapperWithFilter("id", Filter.Operator._EQUAL, applyId);
            RoleCreationApply roleCreationApply = (RoleCreationApply) getByFilter(RoleCreationApply.class, filter);
            Role appliedRole = new Role();
            appliedRole.setRoleUniqueName(roleCreationApply.getRoleName());
            appliedRole.setRoleName(roleCreationApply.getRoleName());
            appliedRole.setRoleDescription(roleCreationApply.getRoleDescription());
            appliedRole.setRoleDisplayName(roleCreationApply.getRoleDisplayName());
            appliedRole.setCreationTime(new Date());
            appliedRole.setCreatedBy(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            Role childRole = (Role) save(appliedRole);
            parentRole.setCreationTime(new Date());
            parentRole.setCreatedBy(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            parentRole = (Role) save(parentRole);
            RoleRelation roleRelation = new RoleRelation();
            roleRelation.setParentRole(parentRole);
            roleRelation.setChildRole(childRole);
            RoleRelation savedRoleRelation = (RoleRelation) save(roleRelation);
            PostRoleRelation postRoleRelation = new PostRoleRelation();
            postRoleRelation.setPost(roleCreationApply.getPost());
            postRoleRelation.setRoleRelation(savedRoleRelation);
            ir.tamin.framework.domain.Resource result = save(postRoleRelation);
            utx.commit();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            utx.rollback();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

and this is save method in `AbstractEntityProxy` class:

```
@Override
    @ProxyMethod
    public Resource save(Resource clientObject) throws ProxyProcessingException {
        checkRelationShips((Entity) clientObject, Method.SAVE, OneToOne.class, ManyToOne.class);
        try {
            entityManager.persist(clientObject);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException(e);
        }
        return clientObject;
    }
```

but when an exception occures for example `Unique Constraint Violated` and it goes to catch block, when trying to execute `utx.rollback()` it complains `transaction does not exist` and so some entities will persist. but i want all to roll back if one fails.

PS: i don't want to use plain JDBC. what is JPA approach?

Comment: The "Unique Constraint Violated" exception will most probably be thrown by the `utx.commit()` statement. When it fails, the transaction indeed ceases to exist. How are you calling `acceptAppliedRole()`? I am guessing it is in a loop and no transaction has started, so roles are saved in their own transaction. The solution is to make sure a transaction begins *before* calling `acceptAppliedRole()`. Take a look at the `@Transactional` annotation, it will save you some manual work.

Comment: ```acceptAppliedRole()``` is not called in a loop. it is called via ajax request for a given ```applyId```.  i have used ```@Transactional``` on the top of my method and it did not help. i start beginning a transaction using ``` utx.begin();```. i want to rollback all persists in case any kind of exception being thrown

Comment: How are you sure that some persists made in this transaction are being committed? Only way that could occur is if your save methods are not connected to the transaction, issuing its inserts separately in separate transactions. Otherwise, an exception on a commit call or any JPA method that might flush, should mark the transaction for rollback and prevent anything from being committed.

Comment: When i debugg, till the time it reaches '''utx.commit()''' nothing is inserted to db. Only when it comes to that line and exception occures those persists which did not face any problem will save successfully and those which had problems will not. But i need to roll back all in case any exception occured in any persists. You can see the '''save()''' method in my question